# Making an HTTP POST call with multipart/form-data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, post, multipart

I'm trying to make a HTTP POST call with multipart/form-data , using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/dcs/rest',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType:'multipart/form-data',
  data: 'dcs.source=boss-web&query=data&dcs.algorithm=lingo&dcs.output.format=JSON&dcs.clusters.only=true', 
  //dataType: "jsonP",
  success: function(jsonData) {alert('POST alert'); data=jsonData ; },
  error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An Ajax error was thrown.');
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
          }
});
```

It doesn't work. Firebug returns an undefined error and the returned `XMLHttpRequst` object  multipart field is set to false.

What can i do to make this work with jQuery? And if it's not possible is there a simple to achieve this?

i.e. idon't need to transfer files , just some data. but the server requires multipart.

Answer (score 11):

`multipart/form-data` doesn't look at like this:

```
dcs.source=boss-web&query=data&dcs.algorithm=lingo&dcs.output.format=JSON&dcs.clusters.only=true
```

This is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Here's an [example](http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/archives/multipartform-data-over-the-wire-example) of how `multipart/form-data` request looks like. And the related [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html).

`multipart/form-data` is quite often associated with uploading files. If this is your case you could take a look at the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which allows you to ajaxify forms and [supports file uploads](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using FormData(), you can upload files via ajax request.

Refer this link for more info: [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

Tutorial about using FormData: [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/comment-page-1/#comments)

Comment: FormData is not compatible with ie8/9

Comment: look here for FormData in ie8/9 hack - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8286934/1429387

Answer (score -1):

This way works:

```
$( "form#upload-form" )
    .attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" )
    .attr( "encoding", "multipart/form-data" );
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    contentType:attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ),
    url: "/adm/oferta_insert",
    data: dados, 
    success: function( data ) { 
        alert( data );  
    }  
});
```

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1273-Setting-Form-EncType-Dynamically-To-Multipart-Form-Data-In-IE-Internet-Explorer-.htm

Comment: What if the data I'm trying to send isn't actually in a full-fledged form?

Comment: I get an error saying attr is not defined for the part that sets the contentType.