# Using .post() and enctype="multipart/form-data" form

Tags: jquery

How do you use a $.post().serialize() to participate with a form that has a enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Was reading the comment to the 3rd answerer here:
[Making an HTTP POST call with multipart/form-data using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537774/making-an-http-post-call-with-multipart-form-data-using-jquery)

What is that referring to?  I just need to submit it, i'm not trying to read the file client-side, but the server script doesn't seem to be reading the data properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can't upload files via ajax.

You can try to fake the ajax-like upload using iframes, other methods, like java and flash uploaders.

Comment: If you are not uploading files, then why do you need that `enctype`? If you are trying to upload a file, then it is not possible.

Comment: Completely incorrect, check out [this article](http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax), it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could some some plugin:
http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#frmMember").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
                        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'member/api/add',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            async: false,
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data: formData,
                            success: function(data){
                                if(data.status=="OK")
                                {
                                    alert(data.message);
                                    memberFormWindow.close();
                                } else {
                                    alert(data.message);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

This work! try!