# 400 (Bad Request) error when trying to post a form to Facebook VIA Ajax & jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, jquery

I am trying to post an image to a Facebook album using a form in my website. I know I get the correct access token because posting without jQuery and AJAX works fine - but redirects me out of my website. To solve that, I've made a jQuery AJAX post, but this gives me an error I don't understand.

I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Components/JQUERY/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Components/JQUERY/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

The code is:

1. Getting the access token and preparing the URL to post to (**It is OK**, posting without jQuery is uploading the picture to Facebook):

   ```
   //....Facebook code for getting the access token...//

   // This is the URL that was originally in the form's action tag//
   $image_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $ALBUM_ID . "/photos?"
   . "access_token=" .$access_token;
   ```
2. HTML of the form:

   ```
   <form name="myform" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
      Please choose a photo:
        <input name="source" type="file"><br/>
      Say something about this photo: <br/>
        <textarea id="fbText" name="message" rows="4" cols="47"> </textarea><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
   </form>

   <div id="results"></div>
   ```
3. The jQuery Code:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myform").validate({
             debug: false,
             rules: {
                 message: "required"   
             },
             messages: {
                 message: "Please insert text."
             },
             submitHandler: function(form) {
                 // do other stuff for a valid form
                 $.post('<?php echo $image_url ?>', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                   $('#results').html(data);
               });
           }
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

Pressing the upload button gives me the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot post a multipart form data with jquery post method. And one more issue is, cross domain communication. You cannot send ajax request to another domain.

For alternatives, see

> [How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe/168488#168488)
>   http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload
>
> [Facebook new javascript sdk- uploading photos with it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264599/facebook-new-javascript-sdk-uploading-photos-with-it)

For sending multipart data through ajax see these links

> [Making an HTTP POST call with multipart/form-data using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537774/making-an-http-post-call-with-multipart-form-data-using-jquery)
>
> [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

or Lastly, you can upload to your server and upload to facebook..

**[EDIT]**

```
var options = { 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback      
    }; 

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Is the example [from here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) will post the form without redirecting me ?

Comment: Thanks, this does post the photo in the background:   `$('#myform').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            });` but do you know why im not getting the alert shown ?

Comment: It should be like this var options = { 
      
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
 
   
    }; 
 
    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options);

Comment: Thanks, can you please update in the answer... its hard to understand from a comment text. :)

Comment: Looks like cross Domain requests can be done.  Add this line: `$.support.cors = true;`  [jQuery support](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.support/)  Add this setting to AJAX:  `crossDomain: true`   [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)