# Send image and text with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, multipartform-data

I'm using javascript's 'formData' to send image files with ajax. How can I attach other data to formData, for example a text string?

JS:

```
$("#post-image").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../build/ajaxes/upload-photo.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

In my PHP I can access the image by using `$_FILES["images"]`. I don't know what to use for my additional data passed with formdata.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add parameters to FormData use [`FormData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData#append%28%29)

```
$("#post-image").click(function(){
    formdata.append('name', 'value');
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../build/ajaxes/upload-photo.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

In PHP use `$_POST["name"]` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the form as multipart.  Here's a SO solution to your question: [Making an HTTP POST call with multipart/form-data using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537774/making-an-http-post-call-with-multipart-form-data-using-jquery)

Not an exact duplicate, so I didn't mark it as such, but it's a direct reference to the solution to your problem.

Edit: you'll notice that some of the answers reference FormData as a solution as well.  Once you get the data posting properly, you can then access it with the normal $_FORM collection in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Big form with Multiple file uploads then not use [MALSUP JQUERY PLUGIN](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) .It will send all your form fields with just

```
  $(form).ajaxSubmit();
```