# Can I pass image form data to a PHP function for upload?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jquery and PHP to upload an image like so:

HTML

```
<form id="form-photo" enctype="multipart/form-data"><
  <span class="btn btn-small fileinput-button">
    <span>Add Photo</span>
    <input type="file" name="photo-img" id="photo-img">
  </span>
</form>
```

Current jquery framework looks like this:

```
$('#photo-img').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];

    //console.log(file);
    name = file.name;
    size = file.size;
    type = file.type;

    // I'll do some validation here before proceeding

    var formData = new FormData($('#form-photo'));

    console.log(formData);

   // How do I pass the image form data to a PHP function via jquery?

});
```

Can I just pass the formData to a PHP function via jquery post?

Comment: Only modern browsers can handle sending files via ajax

Comment: Look at this jQuery plugin for ajax file handling: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: At that point, your form is no different from any other form. Take a look at [Making an HTTP POST call with multipart/form-data using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537774/making-an-http-post-call-with-multipart-form-data-using-jquery) also [jQuery .ajax() documenation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested and working on `Goolge Chrome`, `Opera`, `Firefox`, `Safari`.
**`doesn't work with IE8 or lower`**

#### Javascript

Create a `FormData` object and append the `file` with index `photo-img` and `POST` it to your server with the help of `XMLHttpRequest`

```
$(function() {
  $('#photo-img').change(function(){
    var file  = this.files[0];

    // do your validation here

    var formData  = new FormData();
    formData.append( 'photo-img', file ); // append the file to form data

    var xhr = false;
    if ( typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined' ) {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
      var versions  = [ "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0", "Microsoft.XmlHttp" ];
      for( var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        try {
          xhr = new ActiveXObject( versions[i] );
          break;
        }
        catch(e) {}
      }
    }
    if ( xhr ) {
      // replace test.php with your own upload script url
      xhr.open( "POST", "test.php", true );
      xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() {
        if ( this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
          var response  = this.response || this.responseText;

          /** Do Something with the reponse **/
          response  = $.parseJSON( response );
          if ( response && response.message ) {
            window.alert( response.message );
          }

        }
      }
      // now send the formData to server
      xhr.send( formData );
    }
  });
});
```

#### PHP

A better image upload handling on server side and return a `JSON` object as response

```
<?php
  if ( isset( $_FILES["photo-img"] ) ) {
    $error  = false;
    $image  = $_FILES["photo-img"];
    $code   = (int)$image["error"];
    $valid  = array( IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF );
    $folder = dirname( __FILE__ )."/upload/"; // path to folder to where you want to move uploaded file
    $target = $folder.$image["name"];

    if ( !file_exists( $folder ) ) {
      @mkdir( $folder, 0755, true ) ;
    }

    if ( $code !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
      switch( $code ) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': The uploaded file exceeds the <a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><span class="function-string">upload_max_filesize</span></a> directive in php.ini';
        break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': The uploaded file exceeds the <span class="const-string">MAX_FILE_SIZE</span> directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': No file was uploaded';
        break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': Missing a temporary folder';
        break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': Failed to write file to disk';
        break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': A PHP extension stopped the file upload';
        break;
        default:
          $error  = 'Error '.$code.': Unknown upload error'; 
        break; 
      }
    }
    else {
      $iminfo = @getimagesize( $image["tmp_name"] );
      if ( $iminfo && is_array( $iminfo ) ) {
        if ( isset( $iminfo[2] ) && in_array( $iminfo[2], $valid ) && is_readable( $image["tmp_name"] ) ) {
          if ( !move_uploaded_file( $image["tmp_name"], $target ) ) {
            $error  = "Error while moving uploaded file";
          }
        }
        else {
          $error  = "Invalid format or image is not readable";
        }
      }
      else {
        $error  = "Only image files are allowed (jpg, gif, png)";
      }
    }
    if ( empty( $error ) ) {
      echo json_encode( array( "error" => 0, "message" => "Upload success!" ) );
    }
    else {
      echo json_encode( array( "error" => 1, "message" => $error ) );
    }
    exit();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Clean solution. Nice validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $.ajax method in jquery and send the form data to a php file.

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/index.php",
  data: data,
  success: success,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that $.post and $.ajax are very similar (except by default $.ajax uses type=get, you have to change it to type=post). You have more control over stuff with $.ajax, but $.post is more stream-lined -- think of $.post as a short-hand way of doing an AJAX POST. However, because $.ajax is often more structured than $.post, it is a great way for those new to AJAX to experiment with adding modifiers, such `dataType:JSON`, `contentType`, or even  `async:false`.

Ajax code would like this:

```
$('#photo-img').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];

    //console.log(file);
    name = file.name;
    size = file.size;
    type = file.type;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your_php_file.php",
        data: 'f_name=' +name+ '&f_size=' +size+ '&f_type=' +type,
        success: function(whatigot) {
            alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
        } //END success fn
    }); //END $.ajax
}); //END dropdown change event
```

---

Note that any data coming back from the PHP file comes into your HTML document **in the success function** of the AJAX call, and must be dealt with **there**. So that's where you insert the received data into the DOM.

For example, suppose your HTML document has a DIV with the `id="myDiv"`. To insert the data from PHP into the HTML document, replace the line: `alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);` with this:

```
$('#myDiv').html(whatIgot);
```

Your DIV now contains the data echoed from the PHP file.

---

On the PHP side, it basically looks like this:

```
<?php
    $file_name = $_POST['f_name'];
    $file_size = $_POST['f_size'];
    $file_type = $_POST['f_type'];

    //Here is where you do some stuff, such as MySQL lookups, etc
    //Then build the response to send back (default is HTML, unless 
    //you specify something else like JSON)

    $r = 'The PHP File received:<br><br>';
    $r .= '
        <ul>
            <li>File Name: ' .$file_name.'</li>
            <li>File Size: ' .$file_size.'</li>
            <li>File Type: ' .$file_type.'</li>
        </ul>
    ';
    echo $r;
```

---

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466) for ideas on how it works.

Note that the above examples use jQuery, and therefore require this reference in the  tags of your page:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```